# Add downloadable product to cart from url

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to add a downloadable Magento 2 product to a cart just by giving someone a url?

Answer (score 0):

First get form key using below code :

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$formKey = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');
$key = $formKey->getFormKey();
echo $key;
?>
```

you can add it like :

```
web-url/checkout/cart/add/uenc/{uenc_value}/product/{product_id}/form_key/{form_key_value}/
```

Comment: uenc_value: This is a base64 encoded URL for redirection. For a simple direct add, this is often the encoded version of the store's base URL.